# Label for a results page: List View vs.?

Tags: terminology, labels

I'm working on a look-up tool that enables users to search for various physical assets that they own, and present them with a number of "results", either in a List View or in an Overview (dashboard-like) format.

The "overview" includes a map showing all the results together, as well as widgets that give the user various "totals" based on the sum of all those results (total replacement value, average age, asset types, etc...). So basically ONE dashboard that provides data on ALL the results added together.

I'm not sure what to name this view - I'm including a button on the screen so users can toggle between both (List/Overview), but "overview" doesn't seem quite descriptive enough.

I'm thinking something along the lines of "Rich View / List View", but wondering if there's something better. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm thinking something along the lines of **"Rich View / List View"**, but wondering if there's something even better...

Comment: You describe well what the "overview" includes, but what does the list view show that is different?

Comment: In List view, the user simply sees a list of each physical asset, alongside a map. There are no total costs, no aggregate summary. Just a list with minimal details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about List/Details or Summary/Details?

Comment: Similarly, List View / Dashboard View

Comment: Yes, I was thinking List View / Dashboard View as an alternative (which is really quite representative of what I have). I'll see whether Dashboard View vs. Rich View resonates with the client. Thank you!

Comment: I think Dashboard doesn't fit right with the fact that it's search results. It's not a persistent view that you can return to unless you do the same search to get those same results. "Detailed Results" vs "Summary" represents the data you're showing better.

Answer (score 2):

**Grid view** is generally used when you're showcasing stuff in a gallery fashion.

If you want something different, you can use a terminology and define them: **Card view** or **magazine view** like the feedly news reader does (image below).

[image]

Comment: Good suggestions, except that it's not just a layout thing: the Overview "view" shows more of an aggregate of all the results (not just displayed differently, but it includes charts/graphs/widgets made up of the sum of all the results). But I like the icon concept...

Answer (score 0):

How about Ariel View? It sounds like you're offering an overhead view because you're showing many types of relationships that could only be seen from an overhead perspective. Ariel View works better as a header than Overhead View because it's shorter. It's probably clearer as well.

By Ariel View I mean something similar to Bird's Eye View. It means you're viewing from a highpoint. If the meaning wasn't clear to you, though, it's probably not a good choice for a name. It depends on the application though. Some audiences--pilots, for example!--might appreciate the reference.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow--what do you mean by an "Ariel View"?

Comment: You understand what I'm going for, so thank you! Not sure I understand "ariel view" as well, though... or if it's a term that most people would understand?